# Invalid block tag 'else'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Tags: python, django, jinja2

Why I got this error?
I have this error on django, while it's working correctly on `Flask`.

```
1   {% if user.is_authenticated %}
2     {% extends "home.html" %}
3   {% else %}
4     {% extends "index_not_auth.html" %}
5   {% endif %}
```

> TemplateSyntaxError at /
> Invalid block tag on line 3: 'else'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
> Request Method: GET
> Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
> Django Version: `3.2.2`
> Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
> Exception Value:
> Invalid block tag on line 3: 'else'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
> Exception Location: D:\GitHub Repositories\Django-WebApp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py, line 534, in invalid_block_tag
> Python Executable:  D:\GitHub Repositories\Django-WebApp\venv\Scripts\python.exe
> Python Version: `3.6.1`

Comment: You cannot put the `extends` template tag in an if-else, there can only be one extends tag and it must be at the start of the template.

Comment: you will have to control not authenticated or authenticated page rendering at the server side.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat is right...you probably want to use `include` instead `extends`

Comment: Ok thanks, but i wonder why it actually works on Flask

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot put the `extends` template tag in an if-else, there can only be one `extends` tag in a template and it must be at the start of the template. If you want to dynamically extend templates you should pass the template name in the context from the view and use that variable in the `extends` tag:

```
from django.shortcuts import render


def some_view(request):
    # ...
    context = {}
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        context['parent_template'] = 'home.html'
    else:
        context['parent_template'] = 'index_not_auth.html'
    return render(request, 'some_template.html', context)
```

Now in the template:

```
{% extends parent_template %}
<!-- Rest of template -->
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Now i understand.